# Is it possible to handle multiple rows as a single DOM object?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to handle multiple consecutive table rows (`<tr>`) as a single DOM object? I  have a table whose "logical child" spans for multiple rows (in my particular case, two). When displayed, they are mixed with the other rows, but I want to be able to manipulate (move, delete, hide, etc) those rows as a single DOM object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, place them in their own `<tbody>` element.

```
<table id="my_table">
   <tbody>
       <tr><td> special </td><td> row </td></tr>
       <tr><td> special </td><td> row </td></tr>
   </tbody>

   <tbody>
       <tr><td> normal </td><td> row </td></tr>
       <tr><td> normal </td><td> row </td></tr>
       <tr><td> normal </td><td> row </td></tr>
       <tr><td> normal </td><td> row </td></tr>
       <tr><td> normal </td><td> row </td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

---

```
var table = document.getElementById('my_table');

var special_rows = table.tBodies[0]; // work with just the rows in this tbody
var normal_rows = table.tBodies[1];  // work with the rest
```

Comment: I'm out of votes for the day or else I would +1 you for being right. (@sawa, you handed out the acceptance marker a little too fast. :)

Comment: +1 too. Can you do something like `special_rows.setAttribute('colspan', 2)`? Isn't that what the OP was asking?

Comment: @alex: Hmmm... Perhaps I'm wrong, but I didn't gather that OP wanted only one column, just that the rows in question should be manipulated as a set.

Comment: @amnotiam I may have misinterpreted the question incorrectly.

Comment: I had the feeling that it is possible. I am glad that it is.